# How to create/update and retrieve data from nested objects in Cloud Firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a class that has one embedded array as well as a couple of objects. I  can't figure out how to create/update and read to and from Cloud Firestore. I'm using flutter.

```
class ArtistModal {
 final String artistName;
 final String artistImage;
 final String role;

ArtistModal({
 required this.artistName,
 required this.artistImage,
 required this.role,
});
```

I am trying to embedded artistModal in test modal. I want to read it as a list in UI side. I can't quite figure it out how?

```
class TestModal {
 final String id;
 final String venueName;
 final String eventName;
 List<ArtistModal> artistModal = <ArtistModal>[];

TestModal({
required this.venueName,
required this.id,
required this.eventName,
required this.artistModal,
});

factory TestModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return TestModal(
    venueName: json['venueName'] ?? '',
    eventName: json['eventName'] ?? '',
    artistModal: List.from(json['artistModal'] ?? ''),
    id: json['id'] ?? '');
}

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
return {
  'venueName': venueName,
  'eventName': eventName,
  'artistModal': artistModal,
  'id': id,
  };
 }
}
```

Edited

Alright. And after this can I use this to create/update and read data from Cloud Firestore.

```
Stream<List<TestModal>> fetchListOfTest() {
 return _testCollection.snapshots().map((event) => event.docs
    .map((e) => TestModal.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String,              dynamic>))
    .toList());
 }

Future<void> setTest(TestModal testModal) {
 var options = SetOptions(merge: true);
 return _testCollection.doc(testModal.id).set(testModal.toMap(), options);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of your firestore structure?

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to write a comment, I couldn't ask you what you want to achieve here exactly. I'm assuming that you want to generate a list of ArtistModal and store it in artistModal attribute of class TestModal. If that's the case, you can change your factory method to something like this:

```
    factory TestModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TestModal(
        venueName: json['venueName'] ?? '',
        eventName: json['eventName'] ?? '',
        artistModal: json['artistModal'] != null ?
          List.generate(json['artistModal'].length, (index) => ArtistModal(
            artistName: json['artistModal'][index]['name'],
            artistImage: json['artistModal'][index]['image'],
            role: json['artistModal'][index]['role'],
          )) : [],
        id: json['id'] ?? '');
  }
```

I am assuming that json['artistModal'] contains a list of Map, where the map contains data related to artist modal.

Comment: Please check the edited code. Is that how I will store and retrieve

Comment: Looking at your edited code, fetchListOfTest should work fine since I do not know the structure of your firestore collection.It would be easier to answer If I could have a look at it (you could provide a screenshot).
But, I suppose setTest would not work as intended because we need to convert objects into json structure.

Answer (score 0):

To cleanly convert list of nested objects within Factory method:

```
factory TestModal.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> json) { 
 return TestModal(
  venueName: json['venueName'] ?? '',
  eventName: json['eventName'] ?? '',
  artistModal: List<ArtistModal>.from(json['artistModal'].map((data) => ArtistModal.fromJson(data))) ?? [],
  id: json['id'] ?? '',  
 );  
}
```